# Prevent Maven archetype generate from creating variable

Tags: maven, maven-archetype

I created a Maven Archetype for use in our company projects. Everything worked well until going to deploy a project built from the archetype which failed due to invalid XML.

Within the template I created to generate the archetype from are several .xml files. Each has an XML declaration of:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

When running `mvn archetype:create-from-project` to stamp out the archetype for me, it apparently determined *version* in the XML declaration as a Maven keyword and wrapped it in a variable. The result was that each XML declaration in the archetype became:

```
<?xml ${version}="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

After using the archetype to create a project, Maven obviously replaced this variable with the user-chosen version for the project. This resulted in something like:

```
<?xml 1.0-SNAPSHOT="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

Definitely invalid for XML. My question then is, how can you prevent `mvn archetype:create-from-project` from doing this? Is there a way to limit its scope in some way or set a flag in the command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `-Darchetype.filteredExtentions=extension1,extension2,...` to your `mvn` command to tell maven which file extensions to include when it does its velocity substitutions. This filter *includes* file extensions, so you have make a list of all of your file extensions and leave off xml in order to skip over them. You can do `-Darchetype.filteredExtentions` if `xml` is the only file type in your project.

Comment: That was it! An empty list of files to filter and it didn't touch my XMLs :)